# How to make custom keyboard work with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

i'm making custom keyboard using swift. 
the thing i want is that if i key 'a', 
'a' can appear on the search bar(safari search bar or somewhere)

i combined all alphabet keys to `@IBAction fun didTapKey`.

`@IBOutlet var key` is that setting shadow for key buttons

this is the part of keyboardViewController.swift.
(pls ignore nextkeyboarbutton, this is not the one i created( i think this is kinda default button ;-; )

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
var newKeyboardView: UIView!

@IBAction func didTapKey(sender: UIButton) {

}

@IBOutlet var key: [UIButton]!


@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadInterface()

    for button in self.key {
        button.layer.masksToBounds = false
        button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).CGColor
        button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        button.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    }
```

Comment: Just a side note. You may want to have a look at iOS 10 features.  Depending on the keyboard you're making, it may be completely obsolete by November.  I have 12 keyboards on the store and when iOS 10 is official, they are all almost useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the tapped key letter you pass it to the text field the keyboard is currently focused on.
The text field you get by:

```
let textDocumentProxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput
```

and then you insert your `String` to that proxy:

```
textDocumentProxy.insertText(myString)
```